# Codeigniter default controller not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I have almost finished a web application using Codeigniter. In development, the root directory is **/readme/** and I use the following code in .htaccess to eliminate index.php in the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /readme
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also set **Readme_home** as the default controller, so the following URL will directly points to the default controller:

```
http://localhost/readme
```

For production, I use the exact same configuration as the one for development but the following URL does not work and produce '**Directory access is forbidden**' error:

```
http://www.mydomain/readme
```

Instead, I have to use

```
http://www.mydomain/readme/readme_home
```

for the default controller to appear. Is there any missing configuration? If anyone can point out any reference on the web about this problem, that would be good enough. Let me know if I have to add additional information. Thank you sir, and I really appreciate it.

Comment: Check the folders and files permission, it has to be readable for the web access (eg. chmod 666).

More information on that topic with a [search engine](http://www.google.de/search?q=codeigniter+"Directory+access+is+forbidden").

Comment: I don't think it's a permissions problem. Have you tried using the standard .htaccess script (or no .htaccess file) and just changing the base_url in your config to "http://www.mydomain.com/readme
"? I think CI should just sort the rest out itself.

Comment: I actually tried both approaches but those don't work. Thank anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Depending on your host, your `uri_protocol` might not be detected properly. In your config/config.php file, switch `uri_protocol` to any of the options listed. I've had the same issue when running my app on a VPS. Currently, `PATH_INFO` works.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

Comment: I tried this too, but still no luck. I do agree that this might be the codeigniter configuration or .htaccess. Any other idea?